# How to fix 'Multiply defined' in Keil V5

Tags: embedded, keil, cortex-m, lpc

I am trying to compile my code but I get the error "multiply defined" despite defining my variable only in one header (For example ".\Objects\LCDADC.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol Pin_D6 multiply defined (by lcd.o and main.o).".)

I am using Keil with an LPC1768

main.c

```
#include <lpc17xx.h>
#include "LCD.h"
#include "Delay.h"


//Char LCD Pins
#define LCD_RS P2_0
#define LCD_RW P2_1
#define LCD_E P2_2
#define LCD_D4 P2_4
#define LCD_D5 P2_5
#define LCD_D6 P2_6
#define LCD_D7 P2_7

int main(){
    SystemInit();
    Delay_init();
    LCD_Init(LCD_RS, LCD_RW, LCD_E, LCD_D4, LCD_D5, LCD_D6, LCD_D7);

    int main....
```

LCD.H

```
#include "Delay.h"

uint8_t Pin_RS;
uint8_t Pin_RW;
uint8_t Pin_E;
uint8_t Pin_D4;
uint8_t Pin_D5;
uint8_t Pin_D6;
uint8_t Pin_D7;

void LCD_Init(uint8_t rs, uint8_t rw, uint8_t e, uint8_t d4, uint8_t d5, uint8_t d6, uint8_t d7);

....(More functions)
```

LCD.c

```
#include "LCD.h"
#include "GPIO.h"
#include "Delay.h"

void LCD_Init(uint8_t rs, uint8_t rw, uint8_t e, uint8_t d4, uint8_t d5, uint8_t d6, uint8_t d7)
{
    //Set Pin Numbers
    Pin_RW = rw;
    Pin_E = e;
    Pin_RS = rs;
    Pin_D4 = d4;
    Pin_D5 = d5;
    Pin_D6 = d6;
    Pin_D7 = d7;

    //Set port Directions
    GPIO_PinDirection(Pin_D4, 1);
    ....(same for every pin and some command sending.)

}

....(Other Functions.)
```

(Sorry for posting my entire code but I believe it's important and very short in this case.)

As you can see I clearly only defined my pins only once. so why does it think I'm defining it multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared those variables in header file `LCD.h`. Whenever you include the header file, those variables will be declared.

You have included that file in `main.c` and in `LCD.c` which means two instances of each variable are created. As these variables are Global, you cannot have same names twice. That's why you are getting the error.

To solve that, move those variables in `LCD.c`. If you are not going to use them outside this C file, make them Static. That way, they are restricted to `LCD.c` only.

One more tip (which is unrelated to the error) is you should use [Include Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Your `Delay.h` is getting included multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer :) but if I used the guards would that solve the issues? when using the guard it didn't solve my issues.
when programming for my PC in C++ I always declared my variables in side the .h so I have no idea why it's not working here (EDIT: I am an idiot I forgot this isn't a class...., it's been 2 years since I coded and I'm only just starting again)

Comment: A technicality, but there is a distinction between "_declared_" and "_defined_".  This problem is with multiple _definitions_.  The line `uint8_t Pin_RS;` both declares and defines the variable `Pin_RS`.  You shouldn't normally _define_ variables in header files because the definition will get repeated in every C file that includes the header file.  _Declaring_ global variables in header files _is_ normal.  Add `extern` to make a declaration-only statement (without definition), like `extern uint8_t Pin_RS;`.  And then you would add a single definition statement in one C file.

Comment: @Swanand, What about the external lib? Sometimes has been generated from external lib(eg. stm32f1xx_it.c)